# return only user owned playlist spotify api

Tags: javascript, express, spotify

I want to get a list of playlists that a user owns from Spotify.

I don't want any collaborative or shared playlist, just the playlists the user owns, and can update.

It its [explained here how to get a user's playlist](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-list-users-playlists/).

My code currently looks like this. the problem is that it returns all playlist's that the user has, inlacing ones they do not own, or share. Is there something simple i can do with the auth scope to get just the user's playlist, or do i have to loop through the result's and only put the playlist in the array if the owner matches the playlist owner?

```
app.get('/user-playlists', function(req, res){

    var options = {
        url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
        },
        json: true
    };

    request-promise(options).then(function(body) {
        var userId = body.id;
        var options = {
            url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/' + userId + '/playlists',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
            },
            json: true
        };
        return rp(options).then(function (body) {
            var playlists = body.items;
            res.json(playlists);
        });
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err)
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to retrieve the user's username using the [Get Current User's Profile](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-current-users-profile/), and filter out any playlist that doesn't have the same `owner` value as the user's `id`. There's no endpoint in the API to only retrieve playlists that the user has created.

Comment: cool, thats what i thought. Just wanted to make sure there wasn't an easier way

Comment: Feel free to mark the answer as correct so that others find it easier. (And so that I get imaginary Internet points.) Happy hacking!

Comment: hahah! green tick and a mark up added! enjoy that shiny green  `+25` on your dashboard! :-)